# How to switch elements in a 9*9 matrix

Tags: c++

If I want to switch all the elements "1" to "3" ,and all the elements "3" to "1", then the input is 1 3.
Here's the code, how can I modify it?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void swap1(int *A,int *B){
   int temp=*A;
   *A=*B;
   *B=temp;
   }
int main(){
int a,b;
int temp1,temp2;
cin>>a>>b;
int board[9][9]={
{3,0,2,0,0,5,6,9,0},
{0,4,0,0,9,6,0,3,0},
{0,5,0,0,0,8,0,0,0},
{1,9,0,0,8,0,7,0,3},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{5,0,7,0,3,0,0,6,1},
{0,0,0,8,0,0,0,2,0},
{0,8,0,9,6,0,0,7,0},
{0,6,5,7,0,0,3,0,9},
};
for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
   for(int j=0;j<9;j++){
      if(board[i][j]==a){
         swap1(&a,&b);
         }
      }
   }
for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
   for(int j=0;j<9;j++){
      cout<<board[i][j];
      if(j<8)cout<<" ";
      }
   cout<<"\n";
   }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
swap1(&a,&b);
```

Swaps the values of `a` and `b`, the integers you use to store the user input. If you want to modify the array elements you should rather have something like this inside your loop:

```
if (board[i][j] == a) board[i][j] = b;
else if (board[i][j] == b) board[i][j] = a;
```

(no need to swap)

Comment: @江冠德 The answer above is correct, so obviously you did something wrong, but without seeing your code it's impossible to say what that is.

Comment: @江冠德 funny I think I made the same mistake when I wanted to confirm it, you have to remove your `if` inside the loop, then you get corerct output, see ehre: https://wandbox.org/permlink/J9P45eKDNdg8rz5q

Comment: @江冠德 dont post code in comments, it is not readable, instead you can use online compilers like the one above to share code

Comment: @江冠德 See the mistake `else if(board[i][j]==b) board[i][j]=b;` should be `else if(board[i][j]==b) board[i][j]=a;`. Please try to understand the code you have written yourself. That's an obvious error, easy to make, but the way the program ran only changing one of the numbers should have given you a clue as to what was wrong.